# Cross-browser word breaks

Tags: css, cross-browser, line-breaks, word-break

I've been trying to apply cross-browser (modern browsers) word breaks that works within a fluid layout. My attempt so far has been very close but Firefox has some issues dealing with it and it's hard to find a workaround that doesn't affect the other browsers. Based on http://kenneth.io/blog/2012/03/04/word-wrapping-hypernation-using-css/ I applied this,

```
  text-rendering: optimizelegibility;
  -ms-word-break:   break-all;
  word-break:       break-word;
  word-wrap:        break-word;
  -webkit-hyphens:  auto;
  -moz-hyphens:  auto;
  hyphens:  auto;
```

Yet this seems to cause (line based) breaks within words in Safari (v 7) as well as Firefox (v 27). Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The line based break is caused by `word-wrap: break-word;`. And `break-word` is not a valid value for `word-break`. You should use `break-all` for non-prefixed `word-break` aswell. [Check out MDN for reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break)

As for hyphens, -moz- is supposed to support it but I've never gotten it to work...